# MKStoreKit Restoring Non-Consumable Purchases

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkstorekit

In my new App, I am using *MKStoreKit* to remove adverts. The purchasing side of it works, but as far as the Restore Function goes, nothing will work! I have properly implemented all of the Frameworks and *MKStoreKit* files, yet I get the error:

```
No visible @interface for 'MKStoreManager' declares the selector 'restorePreviousTransactions'
```

The code that I use in my restore IBAction is:

```
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] restorePreviousTransactions];
```

But it just gives me this error!
I am using the latest version of *MKStoreKit* available via Github.
Might anybody have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete:^{
        NSLog(@"Restored");

    } onError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Reseting purchases failed because of error: %@", [error description]);

    }];
```